# Tableau Filter from calculated field, but I want to exclude some

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to add to my current calculated field.

It is a fairly simple LEFT(UPPER([STR]),2) that I am currently using.  This populates a filter list.  However, I want to either modify the formula or the list itself to only include [STR] items where underlying data is and for any that do not have data, they are left off the list until they have data to be selecting.

think of the STR as if it were states abbreviations.  IF COUNT([Things]) = 0 then I don't want the state on my filter list, but if there is or if there later gets some Things added in that state I want it to show up.

I tried using IF COUNT([Things]) > 0 THEN LEFT(UPPER([STR]),2) END but that doesn't seem to work.  I am also open to just using a condition for showing the filter if that can work, but I am not sure how to set that up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely I had tried this solution before.  I choose Show only relevant values on the filter in the filters box, that made it show nothing at all.  However, if you click the drop down arrow on the Show filter card and choose show only relevant values that works.